# Pictures show different color

Tags: html, image

I have the folowing html page http://54.191.80.237/test.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
    1
    <img src="SI-20018_F141_1.jpg" /><br>
    2
    <img src="SI-20018_F141_2.jpg" /><br>
    3
    <img src="SI-20018_F141_3.jpg" /><br>
    4
    <img src="SI-20018_F141_4.jpg" /><br>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

This page shows the pictures in a red color, if you right click the picture and save it, you will see the original color.

Does anyone could point me out in how to fix this, I need to show the original picture colors.

Thanks 
Alberto

Comment: what are you talking about? I opened link, regular glasses, with white background

Comment: In most Browsers yon need to specify width= and height=  which Browser are you using ?

Comment: I saved all the images one by one from the page provided. All are red after saving it as well. Lol :)

Comment: Hello, here is a screenshot the pictures of the left is what I get in the broser, the picture in the right is the uploaded picture,https://www.dropbox.com/s/hsepn5uw5bm67o5/comparison.png?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

Check the color mode of the picture, If it is in CMYK, change it to RGB and check.